# Auth0-js languages webAuth.authorize

Tags: javascript, auth0

How can I change the language of the login page used with `webAuth.authorize({mode: 'login'})`? (webAuth is from the auth0-js package)

In the docs https://auth0.com/docs/universal-login/universal-login-internationalization they say we need to pass a header `Accept-Language` to change the language's login page. but when using `webAuth.authorize()` there is no way to add headers, or am I missing something ?

Another way to do it might be using the `language` from the `AuthorizeOptions` given to `webAuth.authorize(options?: AuthorizeOptions)`, but nothing changes. And looking at the doc, it seems this option is not even supported:

Answer (score -1):

I've found the solution. In Auth0 settings, Universal Login, Login: I modified the code here to add:

```js
var lock = new Auth0Lock(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
...
language: window.navigator.language,
...
}
```

If the navigator language is in your authorized languages (Auth0 settings), it should selecte it, otherwise it will take the default language.

Comment: This answer describes how to do it with the Auth0 `Lock` lib, but the question is specifically about the auth0.js `webAuth` lib, which does not have built-in localization support.